# C# Entity Framework : Rename table field without losing data, using automatic migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework's automatic migrations with a code-first approach.
I dont use the packet manager console and dont have access to coded migrations.

I have a line representing my table in my model here :

```
        public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
```

I renamed one of the fields of Customer :

```
[Table("Customers")]
public partial class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int idCustomer { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string mail { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

I just changed "mail" to "mailModified".
But when the database got updated, Entity deleted all data from the name field.
I think it deleted my column to create a new one with the new name.

How to avoid that ? How to make him understand to only rename the column ?

Thanks for any participation

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: You might have to resort to code-based migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Column Attribute when you create your table class

```
class Table
{
    [Column("ColumnName")]
    public int Column1 { get; set; }
    [Column("ColumnName")]
    public int Column2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to do it using Migration commands.. so that data won't be lost ..

Else u can add the following code to auto-generated up and down method

```
RenameColumn("dbo.MyTable", "NewColumn", "OldColumn");
```

Comment: Correct syntax would be RenameColumn("dbo.MyTable", "OldColumn", "NewColumn");